# Heartbeat on GPIO via config.txt

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+

I want to have an indicator that the Pi is running an wired a LED to GPIO 21 (with a resistor). When manually turning on the LED via `/sys/class/gpio` the LED turns on. Unfortunately, it does not give me a heartbeat when using:

```
dtparam=pwr_led_gpio=21,pwr_led_trigger=heartbeat
```

in the `/boot/config.txt`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What does `sudo vcdbg log msg` say about the params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `dtparam=act_led_trigger=heartbeat` which works on all my Pi.

(I have never tried pwr_led_trigger because the PWR LED is useful and never with an external LED).

I am not sure that this is even possible on the Pi3 the act_led_gpio states "N.B. For Pi3 see pi3-act-led overlay" but there is no corresponding overlay for pwr-led. (The Pi3B+ has totally different power circuitry.)

Comment: works with the act led. The pwr led seems to be hardwired and cannot be changed...